# можно ли восстановить драйвера на win 10 через линукс

Tags: linux, windows-10, драйвер

Такая проблема: поставил iobit driver booster, обновил драйвера (нажал на кнопку обновить все - там было около 18 драйверов для обновления). После перезагрузки винда не грузится (даже колечка загрузки на логотипе после биоса нет, тупо картинка, ждал минут 15-20). На том же компе стоит линукс (debian) - можно ли восстановить/откатить драйвера. Пытался загрузить точку восстановления толку 0...

Comment: *Пытался загрузить точку восстановления толку 0* Точка восстановления - ДО установки iobit driver booster и драйверов? Расшифруйте загадочное "толку 0". Используйте процедуру восстановления загрузки, загрузившись с установочного диска. После неё, возможно, станет доступен безопасный режим, и можно будет откатить проблемные драйверы. Из линукса вряд ли кто даже из прожжённых специалистов возьмётся восстанавливать ОС - крайне непростое действие. *было около 18 драйверов для обновления* Списка этих драйверов у Вас, конечно же, нет...

Comment: @Akina *прожжённых специалистов* - звучит страшно :))))